# setting up subdomain wildcard: configured A record, VirtualHost... still does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, namevirtualhost

Running Apache on CentOS, trying to setup wildcard subdomains,
basically I want .mydomain.com to point to mydomain.com

With cPanel I added *.mydomain.com
With WHM I made sure that A record is pointing to the right IP.

I set my A record:

```
* 14400 IN X.x.x.x
```

My httpd.conf:

```
 ServerName _wildcard_.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html
ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
UseCanonicalName Off

## User userdomain# Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
UserDir enabled userdomain
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup userdomain userdomain
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup usergrdomain userdomain
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RUidGid userdomain userdomain
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mydomain/public_html/cgi-bin/


# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/mydomain/wildcard_safe.mydomain.com/*.conf"
```

I have my VirtualHost in httpd.conf set to point to domain root. Restarted Apache, server, dns, still nothing.

I have spent hours researching this, followed instructions, set everything correctly.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: You forgot to say what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

ServerAlias directive is valid only in VirtualHost context.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Your config should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _wildcard_.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off

    ## User userdomain# Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled userdomain
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup userdomain userdomain
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup usergrdomain userdomain
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RUidGid userdomain userdomain
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mydomain/public_html/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
```